# Ending input() by "if ... is not None" using Python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input, nonetype

I'm very new to Python. I'm trying to make a todo-list (a txt file) that I can then add stuff to. I'm struggling with the correct method of making the script stop when I'm done entering things.

I've tried different ways of making while loops and if statements, but the script always either just stops or goes on forever.

I think the problem might lie with me assigning "not None" to a changing variable, but I'm not sure. This is my code:

```
import time
from datetime import date

todo_file = open(f"ToDos_{date.today()}", 'a')

todo_file.write(input("What do you need to do tomorrow? "))
todo_file.write("\n")

todo = input("What else? ")

if todo is not None:
    todo_file.write(todo)
    todo_file.write("\n")
else:
    pass

todo_file.close()
```

Any other criticisms to how I wrote this are also very welcome.

Comment: `todo` can never be `None` because `input()` always return a string in Python 3, an empty string is returned when you don't provide any textual input. You should probably be checking `if todo != "":`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The script still stops directly after the second prompt (after "What else? "), not letting me add more items.

Comment: Even better @abccd: `if not todo`.

Comment: You need a loop @Samia00. You have several options for how to structure the loop, but the easiest would be a while loop that simply tests when `todo` is empty.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Christian. I now answered my own question with this information, I hope that was the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @abccd and @Christian, the question is solved. Of course, I needed a while loop. I won't mix those up again. The code was also missing an input prompt. It now works and looks like this:

```
import time
from datetime import date

todo_file = open(f"ToDos_{date.today()}", 'a')

todo_file.write(input("What do you need to do tomorrow? "))
todo_file.write("\n")

todo = input("What else? ")

while todo != "":
    todo_file.write(todo)
    todo_file.write("\n")
    todo = input("What else? ")

todo_file.close()
```

Comment: I just stumbled over an even easier way to do the while loop: `while todo:` is enough, as it means "while todo is not empty".